# Division in a SQL statement.

Tags: sql, division

Ok so my question:

I have a table itemconfig where there is lots of data concerning items stored in our warehouses. I need to select a special `group` of items so I can do some job related testing.   So far I've been doing the math in my head as I scroll through the database but there must be an easier way.

Within itemconfig I want to specifically look at columns case_qty and pal_qty and itm_num. What I would like to do is select all itm_num where `pal_qty / case_qty` is greater than say `500`. This would give me all `itm_num` instantly that are relevant to my tests.  Sadly I'm not familiar with how to do this or if it's even possible.

Thanks.

Comment: How do I flag this as answered. And I guess give everyone points or whatever. I don't normally use this place. Also I asked then went to lunch so sorry for delay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Division is implemented in most SQL dialects: use `/`, like this:

```
select * from table
where  pal_qty / case_qty > 500
```

Assuming `case_qty` is non-negative, you can shield yourself from division by zero (and use indexes on `pal_qty`, if any*) by multiplying both sides by `case_qty`:

```
select * from table
where  pal_qty > 500 * case_qty
```

---

* Thanks [Vincent Savard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476496/vincent-savard) for this observation.

Comment: This also has the advantage of allowing the use of an index on column `pal_qty`

Comment: @VincentSavard You are right, this is a great observation, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, using a simple `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
  itm_num
FROM itemconfig
WHERE 
  /* Make sure you don't divide by zero */
  case_qty > 0 AND
  pal_qty / case_qty > 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use division in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT itm_num
FROM itemconfig
WHERE (pal_qty/case_qty) > 500
```

If you will have case_qty that equals zero, then you need to be sure you do not divide by zero

```
SELECT itm_num
FROM itemconfig
WHERE (pal_qty/case_qty) > 500
    AND case_qty > 0
```

Comment: Note that MySQL will happily do a division by zero.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is just sad.