# Rails ".where()" clause with decimal division

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run something like this:

```
@almostFullTopics = Topic.where("(user_submissions_count/submissions_cap) >= .8 ")
```

where user_submissions_count and submissions_cap are both whole numbers. This doesn't work at the moment because the division is not done properly. I essentially need something like this:

```
@almostFullTopics = Topic.where("(user_submissions_count.to_f/submissions_cap) >= .8 ")
```

Any ideas on how I can go about implementing this?

Comment: What database are you running on? Your first attempt appears to work fine on mysql.

Comment: i'm running on postgres

Comment: for example, if user_submissions_count = 7 and submissions_cap = 12, user_submissions_count/submissions_cap should equal .5something, but instead I just get 0. Using to_f makes it work but I can't figure out how to use it within the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in this answer,  [Division in a SQL statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692384/division-in-a-sql-statement) it might be worth approaching this in a different direction.

```
@almostFullTopics = Topic.where("user_submissions_count  >= 0.8 * submissions_cap")
```